# how to use fallbacks in socket.io for providing long polling on a websocket server?

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

I have an existing websocket server which serves json over websockets for IM on some non-http/s port.

This works fine for browsers which support websocket protocol but leaves a lot of other browsers from using the feature.

I was reading up on socket.io and nodejs and was thinking of adding a proxy using socket.io and nodejs in front of the websocket server to handle all websocket requests. Since socket.io supports fallback using flash websockets or long polling, I was hoping that using socket.io on client side will allow support for all older browsers as well.

So, my questions are,

1. Is the above approach feasible?
2. How does the fallback to long polling have to be handled in nodejs? Is it handled automatically or needs to be implemented?
3. Any existing resources which might help me out.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

1. It can be made feasible. However I suggest using NodeJS and Socket.IO for both your non-http request and http request for browsers. NodeJS can handle them very easily.
2. Socket.IO handles fallback automatically.
3. A simple chat system example [here](http://code.google.com/p/nodejs-win/wiki/SimpleChatSystem) for http.

Comment: So, Will the following work ? Here, I'm presuming node.js proxy will only need to declare transport support and just needs to handle that it is a websocket connection on both ends (no special handling for comet or flash socket).

IE6 Browser (socket.io) <=(long poll/flash socket)=> Proxy (node.js+socket.io) <=(websocket)=> WebSocket Chat server